# Node.js (csvtojson) by selecting specific columns from excel

Tags: node.js, excel

I'm testing a new process from my system where I need to import a csv spreadsheet to my `database`, but the excel I'm imputing has many unnecessary columns I'd like to select specific columns for import example:

```
> **VERSION_ID  TN       RN1          DATA         OPERACAO    CN**
> 24246610   3000010300 55115     26/11/2012 22:02     1        11
> 28610111   3000012345 55115     06/08/2013 23:03     1        11
> 23041462   3000026314 55115     18/09/2012 23:01     1        11
> 33418254   3000052576 55115     27/06/2014 01:00     1        11
```

**I need to do the code in the code to select in JSON only the TN and RN1 columns**

My code already converts csv to JSON but it takes all the columns of excel..

Code:

```
var Converter = require("csvtojson").Converter;

var fs=require("fs"); 
//CSV File Path or CSV String or Readable Stream Object
var csvFileName="teste.csv";

//new converter instance
var csvConverter=new Converter({});

//end_parsed will be emitted once parsing finished
csvConverter.on("end_parsed",function(jsonObj){
    console.log(jsonObj); //here is your result json object
});

//read from file
fs.createReadStream(csvFileName).pipe(csvConverter);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var Converter = require("csvtojson").Converter;
var firebase = require("firebase");
var express = require("express");
var fs=require("fs");


  csv({noheader:true,
      delimiter:";"})
  .fromFile(csvFilePath)
  .on('json',(jsonObj)=>{
      // combine csv header row and csv line to a json object
      // jsonObj.a ==> 1 or 4
      var TN = jsonObj.field2;
      var cod_op = jsonObj.field3;
      var msisdn = TN.toString();
      noticia.child(msisdn).set(cod_op);
      console.log(TN + ' ' + cod_op);



  })
  .on('done',(error)=>{
      console.log()
  })
```